# How to set dynamical text with images and videos

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uitextview

In my Xcode project I download text and image/video links from a server. Now i want to set this informations into textview's / imageview's. But I don't know how to set the height of a textview because the text have a different length. So what i mean is - I want to have a dynamical view.

When I parse the sample text:

SampleTextSampleTextSampleTextSampleTextSampleTextSampleText **#Video#** SampleTextSampleTextSampleTextSampleText **#Image#** SampleTextSampleText

Now I want to set the different Images und Videos for the tags (#Video# and #Image#)

I hope you know what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
[textView sizeToFit];
```

it should work.